# Dependency Injection - Cannot use object of type Closure as array

Tags: php, oop, dependency-injection

I am trying to integrate a simple dependency injection design pattern in my application since it is only small. Here is the class:

```
class Factory
{
    private static $_models = array();

    public static function set(
        $callback,
        $controller,
        $args = array()
    ) {
        if( is_callable( $controller ) ) {
            // store the controller and args to the array key callback
            self::$_models[$callback] = array(
                'args' => $args,
                'controller' => $controller
            );
            return;
        }
        // if the controller isn't a function return
        throw new Exception("Undefined Closure.");
    }

    public static function get(
        $callback,
        $action
    ) {
        if(self::$_models[$callback]) {
            // execute the closure to receive controller array
            $prefix = call_user_func(self::$_models[$callback]['controller']);
            if(is_callable($prefix[$action])) {
                // execute the closure with or without args
                return count($prefix['args']) < 0 ? $prefix[$action]($prefix['args']) : $prefix[$action]();
            }
            // couldn't find the function so return an error
            throw new Exception("Undefined action: $action.");
        }
        // couldn't find the callback so return an error
        throw new Exception("Undefined callback: $callback.");
    }
}
```

When I try to set a controller like this:

```
Factory::set('example', function($arg) {
    return array(
        'controller' => function() {
             global $arg;
             return $arg;
         }
    );
}, array('value'));
```

I receive this error:

> Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type Closure as array

And the code doesn't get to this part:

```
print_r(Factory::get('example', 'controller')); // expected output array: 'value'
```

Comment: I think you need to do more `isset`-checks. There are a lot of places where you can run into issues. That aside, I think here `Factory::set('example', function($arg) {` the `$arg` is misplaced, and should instead be used on `'controller' => function() {`.

Comment: True, the `args` is a bit of a miss or hit right now, I just want a skeleton version working but I can't see why a closure cannot be stored in an array? @Yoshi

Comment: Oh it sure can. What php version are you using? In my tests (v7x) I can't reproduce your error message. Maybe you can also describe what the class should accomplish, might be better ways to write it (no `global` for example).

Comment: Ah, I am running it on 5.6 but for some strange reason, it won't tell me what line it causing the error.. & well, I wanted to take an AngularJS approach.. rather than writing specific classes, the idea is that the controller and model is just called as and when it is needed @Yoshi

Comment: Ok, I guess there are just some inconsistencies between your `set/get` methods. In `set` you explicitly define `controller` and `args` as keys on the stored array, yet in `get` you require `'controller'` to be passed in but also use it as a fixed array key. I think in it's current form the class could be greatly simplified, e.g. https://3v4l.org/633a8

Comment: well, that was the idea - the `set()` shouldn't know what model it is taking in and what that model consists of (method wise) because it is being injected. The `get()` method simply executes the model method, ie like this: https://3v4l.org/DHDC9 @Yoshi

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133796/discussion-between-yoshi-and-kdot).